# WCF service EndPointNotFoundException - incorrect proxy server error message

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

I have a Visual Studio application which makes heavy use of WCF services. Normally, the team can just download the app from SVN and run and it uses proxy settings from IE and everything is fine.

A new member of the team has just tried to do the same and as soon as the code tries to connect a service client the message similar to below is shown

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://servername/Service.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond *10.1.2.252:8080*
```

It is interesting that 10.1.2.252:8080 should be mentioned as I can find no mention of that in either IE proxy settings or netsh so I have no idea where it is originating from.

I can bypass the problem by adding ***useDefaultWebProxy="false"*** to the bindings but as no other users get this I want to get to the bottom of this.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where the incorrect proxy address may be originating from - (it is not in any files in the solution as I have searched for it)?

Comment: Ask your system administrators. Perhaps the new machine is not configured like the others, or it's in a different VLAN, or a different Active Directory group causing a different proxy autodiscovery to be loaded, or ... We can't answer this.

Comment: have you tried `ping http://servername/Service.svc` from the command line? Is this a public or private webservice? You will have to look at the `innerexception` of the `exception` to know if its the service or the binding. My guess is that your user is using a different `proxy` to the rest of your colleagues

Comment: System admins are perplexed, as I asked them before posting here.The service is private. If the user with the problem pastes the service address into a browser it responds as you would expect and is healthy. Proxy is set by group policy and is identical for all users. It is only when connecting via WCF in Visual Studio that this occurs.

Comment: could you share more details from your web.config file?